# How do I return a byte or short from inline assembly

Tags: gcc, inline-assembly

When I compile:

```
short foo (short x)
{
  __asm ("mov %0, 0" : "=r" (x));
  return x;
}
```

I get

```
foo:
  mov r0, 0
  sxth r0, r0
  bx lr
```

I don't want the extra instruction sxth (signed extract halfword).

The reason it is there is because the ABI (ARM AEABI in this case) requires that the function return value is sign extended to a full register, but GCC doesn't know what my assembly code might have done to the register it gave me.

How do I tell GCC that I promise to leave the register correctly sign extended so it doesn't have to insert this extra instruction?

I would have thought that it could infer this from the fact that I gave it a short as the expression for the "=r" constraint.

Comment: I don't have an arm build to test this with, but maybe some variation of: `int a; asm ("mov %0, 0" : "=r" (a) : "0" (x)); return (short)a;`?